# Terminology of "Random variable"

Tags: terminology, random-variables

A **random variable $X$** is a measurable function $X : \Omega \rightarrow E $ where $\Omega$ and $E$ are measurable sets. So, as far as I can see from this definition, random variables are just measurable functions. I can not see any randomness it it and I suppose it's also not a variable. Then what is the reason behind this terminology ?

Comment: That is not what a random variable is, really, because you haven't given a definition of what it means for two random variables to be the same, and also $\Omega$ should be equipped with a probability measure. Terence Tao has some notes on probability on his blog that discuss this issue very well and thoroughly.

Comment: How about if I generalize this concept, i.e. $\Omega $ and $E $ can have any suitable measure? (I edited my tag). And do we really need the comparison of two random variables here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ahem... "a definition of what it means for two random variables to be the same" This is unnecessary to define the notion of random variable. "Ω should be equipped with a probability measure" Not necessarily, unless you want to compute the distribution of X, but this is not needed to define what is a random variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a sample space $\Omega$ as the set of all possible outcomes from some experiment. A sigma algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ consists of events, which are collections of outcomes. A probability measure $P$ defined on $\mathcal{F}$ tells you how likely events are. One can think of a sigma algebra as containing information that is available, because we can say something about an event in $\mathcal{F}$ (e.g., its probability), but not about subsets of $\Omega$ that are not in $\mathcal{F}$.

A random variable $X:\Omega \to E$ can be thought of as a measurement taken when some experiment has occurred. That is, $X$ takes outcomes (elements $\omega \in \Omega$) and tells us something about them (namely, $X(\omega)$).

As an example, say $\Omega$ is the set of strings of $H$, $T$ of length $5$ (i.e., $\{HHHHH,HHHHT,HHHTH,\dots,TTTTT\}$, the outcomes of five coin flips), $\mathcal{F}$ is the power set of $\Omega$, and $X$ is the number of heads in an outcome. So, for example, $X(HHHHH)=5$, and $X(HTTHT)=2$. The "experiment" consists of flipping five coins (resulting in an outcome in $\Omega$), and the "measurement" $X$ tells us how many heads there were. In a sense you're right that $X$ isn't "random" - it deterministically maps outcomes in $\Omega$ to an integer in $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$. But randomness is encoded in the "experiment" itself, so in that sense $X$ is still a random quantity, and it makes sense to ask what, say, $P(X=3)$ is.

Because random variables are simply defined as measurable functions on probability spaces, they need not actually be "random" in the colloquial sense of the word. Constants are random variables (they are always measurable).

Comment: Random variables can be defined on any measurable space not only probability space. And please correct me if I am wrong -  mathematically speaking, randomness means each outcome is equally probable and this may not always happen.

Comment: I have only seen random variables defined on probability spaces, so I can't speak to your first comment. Randomness need not mean equally likely outcomes - for example if you flip an unfair coin, heads might be more likely than tails. However the outcome is still random, even though heads and tails are not equally likely.

Comment: @kccu in your example, if on the standard probability triple + Lebesgue measure I define $A$: event, such that one or more heads were observed, and $X(\omega)$ as you defined, if I want $\{\omega: X \in (2, \infty)\}$, which of the two sets $\in \mathcal{F}$: A or $B=(2, \infty)$? That's my confusion. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex Do you mean $A=\{\omega : X(\omega) \in [1,\infty)\}$? Remember that $\mathcal{F}$ contains subsets of the sample space $\Omega$ (in this case strings of $H,T$ of length $5$), so $A \in \mathcal{F}$. Notice that $A=X^{-1}(B)$, so $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Yes thanks I meant $B=(1,\infty)$. If probability space is $\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{R}), \mathbf{P}$), is $B \in \Omega$ too, not just $X^{-1}(B)$? I asked two questions, and the solutions just don't quite make sense for piecewise $X(\omega)$, e.g. to find $X^{-1}(B)$, we need to take the intersect of $B$ (image of $X$) with $\Omega$ (domain of $X$)?

Comment: @Alex If $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $B=(1,\infty)$, then $B$ is a *subset* of $\Omega$ (not an element of it). It is an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. But if you are looking for $P(\{\omega : X(\omega ) \in B\})$, then it's not necessarily meaningful to think of $B$ as an subset of the sample space $\Omega$.

Comment: @kccu thanks, sorry, it was all a confusion start to end due to the terminology + misunderstanding about the questions.